# Magento 2 get catalog price rule Action applied and Discount Amount on product list page

Tags: product-list, magento2.2.2, catalog-price-rules

I would like to display text for each product on product list page for a e.g on a category all product with discount but there are 4 options which consist of `percentage` or `fixed` :

[image]
[image]

So if Apply is `Apply as percentage of original` that means the display will be= "x% Discount" if Apply is `Apply as fixed amount` the display will be any currency = "$x Discount" etc... How do I get the selected drop down value
to define if is `percentage` or `fixed` value?

So the goal is to check which one to display either `%` or a currency symbol e.g `$`